# Parent and child data to in memory parent and children list structure

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have parent/children data from DB two tables like so:

```
ParentID, ParentName, ChildID, ChildName
1, 'Parent 1', 10, 'Child 10'
1, 'Parent 1', 11, 'Child 11'
2, 'Parent 2', 12, 'Child 12'
3, 'Parent 3', 13, 'Child 13'
```

I cannot work out how to get an in memory structure such as parent and list of it's children in VB.Net/Linq!

So I would like a list with Parents 1, 2 and 3 with nested lists of their children.

I've tried grouping like so, but it does not place all children in the list, the list only contains one child.

```
Dim Grouped = (From AllData In ParentAndChildren
                Group By AllData.Parent Into g = Group
                Select New With {Parent, .Children = g.Select(Function(x) x.Child).ToList}).ToList
```

Comment: Not clear. Please add the _Parent/Child_ classes. Is it a tree structure? If yes, a recursive/iterator method is what you need.

Comment: Why don't you get the data from the two tables separately?

Comment: I was thinking instead of two calls to the DB, I may be able to get away with one.